# Wrong row count in longtable with xcolor and headers/footers

Tags: numbering, color, longtable

I am trying to color every other row in a `longtable` using the `xcolor` package with the `table` option as shown in this MWE (`landscape` and `17pt` options are only used to shorten the MWE):

```
\documentclass[oneside,landscape,17pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tableRows1}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{tableRows2}{gray}{0.4}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{4}{tableRows1}{tableRows2}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
    \hiderowcolors
    \toprule
    Column 1    &   Column 2    \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsl{Continued from previous page}}\\
    \toprule
    Column 1    &   Column 2    \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    %
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsl{Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    %
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsl{Last foot}}
    \endlastfoot
    %
    \showrowcolors
    11  &   12 (\number\rownum) \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE.]

As you can see, the coloring begins on the first line (not including the column descriptions) although I have specified it to begin at row 4 (`\rowcolors{4}{tableRows1}{tableRows2}`). Clearly some calculations are wrong(?) since row 1 is viewed as row 20 as shown in the parenthesis in row 1, column 2.

Why is that? And how do I change it to get the "correct" behavior?

Note: The offset roughly corresponds to the number of rows in the .tex-document from the beginning of the `longtable` to the first line of data, i.e. header and footer specification might be counted as part of the table. Commenting for instance the `\multicolumn` lines will reduce the number (20) on the first row.

Comment: You can reset the rownum counter: `\noalign{\global\rownum=1}\showrowcolors`

Comment: the longtable head and foot are set at the start of the table internally and then just extracted and re-inserted as the pages are broken, so the easiest thing to do is just count the way you indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the counter after the processing of header rows:

```
\documentclass[oneside,landscape,17pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tableRows1}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{tableRows2}{gray}{0.4}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{4}{tableRows1}{tableRows2}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
    \hiderowcolors
    \toprule
    Column 1    &   Column 2    \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsl{Continued from previous page}}\\
    \toprule
    Column 1    &   Column 2    \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    %
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsl{Continued on next page}}
    \endfoot
    %
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsl{Last foot}}
    \endlastfoot
    %
    \noalign{\global\rownum=1}%<---
    \showrowcolors
    11  &   12 (\number\rownum) \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
    11  &   12 \\
    21  &   22 \\
    31  &   32 \\
    41  &   42 \\
    51  &   52 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]